# Since I'm using comma in this phrase can I remove "and then"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Since I'm using comma in this phrase can I remove `and then` ?

> He walked down the street, and then he turned the corner.

Is it correct to write like this :

> He walked down the street, he turned the corner.

Comment: Commas go wherever you feel comfortable with them as if you were speaking.

Comment: Your second version is not idiomatic. _He walked down the street and turned the corner_ or _He walked down the street, turned the corner and went into a shop_ (or whatever was the next thing that happened).

Comment: You may want to research "comma splice". It is often considered an error.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. That's clearly joining two sentences with a comma, which is an error called a "comma splice."

*He walked down the street. He turned the corner. The sun came out of the clouds.*

*He walked down the street and turned the corner. Just then the sun came out of the clouds.*